# Userform with variable size

Tags: excel, vba, userform

In my program a string gets created and its size varies a lot.

This string should then be shown in a separate window.

Unfortunately the regular *Msgbox* (limited to 1024 signs I believe) is too small for my needs.

Now I created a *Userform* for the issue but of course it looks silly when there is a giant *Userform* and only two values inside, but next time I need the size since there are 1000 values in the string.

I noticed that the regular *Msgbox* changes size depending on how long the string inside it is.

How can I create a userform that changes its size depending on its content?
I only found information on how to make it full screen, which isn't helpful for this case.

The only  real code that I can show you is something generic like this:

```
Sub Ausgabe1()

Dim Werte As Variant
Dim x As Integer

For i = 0 to X
Werte(i) = i
Next i

MsgBox Werte

End Sub
```

Comment: Your question has no definitive answer. There can be many ways to handle this. I believe your question will end up getting closed if you do not amend your question :) You may want to see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). One way to achieve what you want is to create a Small userform and put a textbox with multiline set to true. Adjust the textbox size to occupy70-80% of the userform space... Also set the `TextBox1.ScrollBars = fmScrollBarsVertical` Now show the string in that textbox...

Comment: Another way could be to tick autosize your textbox and adjust width and height of your userform to the textbox's width and height (plus about 20 extra in height to account for the userform's titlebar) upon initialize.

Comment: I just updated the question and hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can vary the value of the width property. How I would do it is to create the userform with a text box and give the userform a displaytext property.

```
Property Let DisplayText(s as String)
Dim x as Long
x = Len(s)
If x > 0 Then 
   Me.Textbox1.Width = x*.7
   Me.Width = Me.Width * 100/x
Else
   Me.Textbox1.Width = 75      ' (edited)
   Me.Width = 100
End If

End Property
```

And then I'd call it like this

```
Load Userform1
With Userform1
   .DisplayText = "your message here"
   .Show
End With
```

You'll have to play with the numbers in the code to get them to fit your screen resolution etcx